# How to get image itselfs?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm making xamarin apps application and I want to edit images with it. How can I get image to make some work with it? (I want to edit some pixels)

```
        var result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions()
        {
            Title = "Выберите изображение" //Eng: Pick image
        });

        var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();

        image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
```

Comment: the stream or filepath returns the raw image data.  You would need to use SkiaSharp or something similar to create a bitmap from that image data and then manipulate it